# How to Display Help In Wizard's Tray

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin

I want to open a help URL inside the tray of an wizard. That's what I came up with:

```
import org.eclipse.help.ui.internal.views.*;

public static void openHelpInWizard(Shell activeShell, String href) {
    if (HelpTray.isAppropriateFor(activeShell)) {
        TrayDialog dialog = (TrayDialog) activeShell.getData();

        DialogTray tray = dialog.getTray();
        if (tray == null) {
            tray = new HelpTray();
            dialog.openTray(tray);
        }
        if (tray instanceof HelpTray) {
            ReusableHelpPart helpPart = ((HelpTray) tray).getHelpPart();
            helpPart.showURL(href);
        }
    }
}
```

For modularization it's bad that this code has dependencies to `org.eclipse.help.ui` (the help is inside another plug-in), but it might be tolerable as an optional dependency. Even worse is that the code has to use internal classes.

So what is the correct way to do this?

Comment: Since it uses internal classes which is explicitly forbidden this is definitely not 'correct'. However I don't think there is a correct way of doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was really hard to find: If the `IContext` implementation returns `null` via `getText()` and has exactly one `IHelpResource` when `getRelatedTopics` is called the "href" of the one help resource is displayed.

So if you want to do what I did, you can implement `IContext` with the above mentioned properties, or use the extension point `org.eclipse.help.contexts` with a *context.xml* like this:

```
<contexts>
    <context id="my_id">
        <topic href="html/help_topic.html" label="My Help Topic"/>
    </context>
</contexts>
```

(I think the "label" attribute is not necessary.)

And then of course use the context ID like this (which doesn't even have a dependency to the help plug-ins):

```
PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getHelpSystem().displayHelp("my_id");
```